# Javascript IIEF - if it's not possible to access any variable then why can I access that through a function?

Tags: javascript, iife

I have read so much about this topic but it's still not clear to me...

If IIFE is all about privacy (//+not polluting global name space...//) then why can I access an IIFE variable using a function argument?
It will show 1200 as the result.

So no I know that "a" is 200, so I have accessed that. What's the logic behind this? Why I can access that variable if everybody says I can't?

```
(sum=function(b){
  var a= 200;
  return a+b;

})();
console.log(sum(1000)); //1200 
console.log(a); //error as expected
```

Part2: if an IIEF is gone once it's called, then why can I execute it as many times as I wish?

```
(sum=function(){

  console.log("random text");

})();

sum(); /*this can relaunch the function even "iief is only used once" + I can do that multiple times
sum(); //'random text' 'random text' ...
```

part 3:

Why I can relaunch the snippet when I give name to the IIEF? I have read everywhere that an IIFE is used only once... once they launch and they are gone..

```
(function sum(){

  console.log("random text");

})();

sum(); //I can execute the IIEF as many times as I wish however I shouldn't be able to
```

Comment: Your last sample does not work the way you say it does. If you try that in an environment where there's no global `sum` function, it throws an error.

Comment: Please stop moving the goalposts. You asked a question, then you got an answer. Then you started editing and now you have three questions. (Your last one is based on a false premise. It throws an exception when I run it).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that answers will come that fast, I have just a lot of confusion about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an IIFE there.

The code between the `(` and `)` assigns a function to the implicitly global variable `sum`.

Then the `()` after it then executes the result of evaluating the expression (which is that same function).

Answer (score -1):

You sample code does not explicitly declare `sum` as a variable, so it's *implicitly global*.  Basically your code is interpreted as this, if it were at the global level in a script:

```
var sum = function(b) {
  var a = 200;
  return a+b;
};
sum();
console.log(sum(1000));
```

Generally the point of an IIFE is to create a namespace that can eventually be exported carefully to a limited number (hopefuly 1) of global symbols. Inside the private namespace of the function, all sorts of data structures and functions can be declared and over time manipulated, all in total isolation from other code.

I think the key error in your code is the assumption that it's necessary to *save* the anonymous function somewhere. That's not a common thing to do, in my experience; usually it looks like:

```
(function(args) {
  // code, possibly a whole lot
})(parameters);
```

Comment: I realize that sometimes, in fact often, an IIFE is a way of writing code to do one particular thing in an isolated environment, without any binding of services to any global symbol.

Comment: I feel so dumm but this IIEF topic is just too much for my newbie brain. Thank you for the answers, I will take a break and continue to read the answers and try to understand these things eventually. Thank you very much and have a nice day!